# KeePass wildcard in url

Tags: regex, url, keepass, wildcards

I started using Keepass yesterday and it's really useful however  I cannot find a way to add wildcard into the url...

I want one key being used on all url(s) that met the following rule:

```
http://www*.domain_name.ext
```

Then surfing to:

```
http://www.domain_name.ext
http://www1.domain_name.ext
http://www11.domain_name.ext
http://www12.domain_name.ext
http://www9999.domain_name.ext
```

will automatically fill user/password...

How can I obtain that?

Comment: I don't understand: KeePass does not use the URL field to match entries; maybe some extensions do, but it's not obvious from the question what you are using.

Answer (score 8):

Original poster, are you using KeeFox plugin ? ( If not, it's advisable because it will solve your issue. )

A solution that worked for me was :

1. install Firefox web browser, this does not work in Chrome or Iexplore as far as I know
2. install KeeFox plugin and ensure it works with keepass on some test website like gmail.com
3. in URL field, enter : domain_name.ext
4. in KeeFox tab -> URLs tab enter: ^.*.domain_name.ext/.* -> Regular expression ticked, Match ticked
5. test. Worked for me.

Comment: Something like `^.*foo.com.*` will match `foo.com`, `http://foo.com/bar`, `https://www.foo.com`, etc - `^` matches start, `.` matches any character, and `*` matches zero or more of the previous.

Comment: @BrianBurns that also matches http://barfoo.com

Comment: @dube Yeah, and I guess ^.* is kind of redundant - i.e. do either ^foo or .*foo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a wildcard solution but you can use references to re-use the username and/or password from one key in another.

You'd have to set up a key for each URL once but you'd only have to maintain the credentials in the master key.

See http://keepass.info/help/base/fieldrefs.html for more details.

Another thing that may match what you are looking for closer is how auto-type matches the window, look at http://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html.
If the different URL's contain the same title auto-type might work on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use regular expression.  So:

`http://www*.domain_name.ext`

would be represented as:

`//http:\/\/www.*\.domain_name\.ext//`

Depending on what browser you are using and [what extension you are using](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-in-title/ignpacbgnbnkaiooknalneoeladjnfgb) to get the [URL into the title bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/keepass-helper/), you may have to add something like this:

`//.\*http:\/\/www.*\.domain_name\.ext/ - Chromium//`

More on regular expressions can be found ... well, it won't let me post any more links.

Comment: Here's the [regexp link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).  Also, [another Chrom(e|ium) extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/domain-in-title/bodphonkppglbgndfcladhogaciihdhb).

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards but they need to be regex wildcards so:

1. you use `.*` instead of just a `*`
2. you need to wrap everything between double forward slashes `//`
3. you need to escape special regex characters (like `/` or `-`)

Say you wanted to save the same username and password for all *.wordpress.com domains. Your easiest option would be to use the following URL expression:

`//.*wordpress.com//`

This basically boils down to `*.wordpress.com` as we normally understand wildcards.

If you really want to specify a protocol (so that KeePass only worked on HTTPS) you would need to escape the forward slashes:

`//https:\/\/.*wordpress.com//`

You can try out your URL expressions on any regex tester tool ([example](http://www.regexpal.com/)) but just don't include the `//` at the start and the end when you test. These double-slashes are just for use in KeePass to let them know you are using regex.